# Relational condition check in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi I am trying to validate at least one of field is required in Django rest framework  json .

Here is my serializer class

```
class WorkloadPutSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    vdi = VdiSerializer(required = False)
    db = DbSerializer(required = False)
    vm= VmSerializer(required = False)
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
```

I want to force  user to enter either `vdi`  or `vm`   or both .

Is there any way to do validate this condition in django rest framework .Please help me out I am not able to  find out in Django rest Framework Documentation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not overriding `validate()` on serializer? See [Object-level validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

```
class WorkloadPutSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    vdi = VdiSerializer(required = False)
    db = DbSerializer(required = False)
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Check if at least one of data['vdi'] or data['vm']
        exists and then return the data. Otherwise raise 
        ValidationError. 
        """
        if data['vdi'] or data['vm']:
            return data
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("No No No")
```

Comment: This will trigger an error for partial updates if either field wasn't passed in. You should be checking if the field exists in the data first.